# UICollectionViewCell custom subview doesn't receive focus

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I created custom Poster view so it can be reused in multiple collection view cells (just like TVPosterView in TVUIKit). I add it directly to cell content view with all needed constraints.

The problem is when cell is focused this subview doesn't receive focus update (didUpdateFocus..) so I cannot customize it's focused / unfocused constraints etc. It's odd btw that image view inside is getting floating effect.

In case if I specify cell's preferredFocusEnvironments to `return [self.posterView] + super. preferredFocusEnvironments`, UI behaves as expected, but the collection view delegate method didSelect not called!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems didUpdateFocus not called on all subviews for the focused cell and it's system design. From docs:

> After the focus is updated to a new view, the focus engine calls this
> method on all focus environments that contain either the previously
> focused view, the next focused view, or both, in **ascending** order. You
> should override this method to update your app’s state in response to
> changes in focus. Use the provided animation coordinator to animate
> changes in visual appearance related to the update. For more
> information on animation coordinators, see
> UIFocusAnimationCoordinator.

Note: So it means `didUpdateFocus` will be called first on UICollectionViewCell, than on UIViewController subclasses, in **ascending** order. For subviews you need to manually register `customDidUpdateFocus` method that will be triggered in notification update. E.g. to update it's appearance we can use notifications (tvOS 11+), please see the example below.

```
func customDidUpdateFocus(isFocused: Bool, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) { /* Custom logic to customize appearance */ }

// Register observer
observerToken = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIFocusSystem.didUpdateNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] (note) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        guard let context = note.userInfo?[UIFocusSystem.focusUpdateContextUserInfoKey] as? UIFocusUpdateContext else { return }
        guard let coordinator = note.userInfo?[UIFocusSystem.animationCoordinatorUserInfoKey] as? UIFocusAnimationCoordinator else { return }
        
        if let prev = context.previouslyFocusedView, self.isDescendant(of: prev) {
            self.didUpdateFocus(isFocused: false, with: coordinator)
        } else if let next = context.nextFocusedView, self.isDescendant(of: next) {
            self.didUpdateFocus(isFocused: true, with: coordinator)
        }
    }
```